# g++ error: expected primary-expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

look at this sample:

```
struct parent
{
    template <typename t>
    inline static t get_t();
};

struct child : public parent
{
    template <typename t>
    inline static t get_t()
    {
        return t(-1);
    }
};

template <typename t>
struct call
{
    inline static int get_value()
    {
        return t::get_t<int>();
    }
};

typedef call< child > test;

int main()
{
    int v = test::get_value();
}
```

The code compile with the following error:

```
In static member function 'static int call<t>::get_value()':
  error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
  error: expected ';' before 'int'
  error: expected unqualified-id before '>' token
```

When i compiled the code with visual c++ 2008 and Intel C++ it compiles without problem.

What that error mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the template qualifier:

```
return t::template get_t<int>();
```

See:

[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 0):

just add

> template

keyword:

```
template <typename t>
struct call
{
    inline static int get_value()
    {
        return t::template get_t<int>();
    }
};
```