# Unreasonable `expected primary-expression error`

Tags: c++, templates, gcc4.8

Just a code sample:

```
template <typename E> class TypeWrapper
{
protected:
  template <typename O> void m_add_object()
  {
  }
};


template <class T> class PyType: public TypeWrapper<T>
{
  void call()
  {
    TypeWrapper<T>::m_add_object<PyType<T> >();
  }
};
```

It's a part of a large project, as small as possible. All templates used and required.

This code invariably failed to compile with reason:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

I tried to fully qualify all members and to use **typename** keyword. It doesn't help.
I think there is invisible **cyclic dependency or compiler bug?**

My environment: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1); Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Short answer: use `template` here: `TypeWrapper<T>::template m_add_object<...>()`

Comment: Yes, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792462/g-error-expected-primary-expression too